# The joke office

Tags: logical-deduction, liars

> Alice and Bob are supposed to get **form A** at the joke office.
>
> **Forms A, B, C, D and E are each at exactly one of the following five terminals. At one Terminal is only one form.**

**Terminal 1:**
 *Here there are form B.*

**Terminal 2:**
 *Here there are form C or E.*

**Terminal 3:**  *Here there are form D.*

**Terminal 4:**
 *Here there are form A, C or E.*

**Terminal 5:**
 *Here there are form A.*

Bob is ​​at a loss when he reads 
 the signs at the counters.

Alice remembers what the janitor 
 is said: ***"Exactly one statement on the terminals is wrong, the four other statements are true."***

**Question:**

> At which terminal is form A 
>     available?

Comment: Is switch the right word, or were you looking for "counter" or "terminal" ?

Comment: Yes, terminal is better.

Comment: You should specify that at each terminal there is exactly one form, otherwise there are alternate solutions, for example with B at 1, C and E at 2, D at 3 and A at 5.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Notation: (P,Q,R,S,T) denotes that form P is in Switch 1, Q in Switch 2, etc.

If Switch 1 is wrong, then

> (?,C/E,D,C/E,A), only choice left for ? is B -> **contradiction**

If Switch 2 is wrong, then

> (B,?,D,C/E,A), only choices left for ? are C and E -> **contradiction**

If Switch 3 is wrong, then

> (B,C/E,?,C/E,A), only choice left for ? is D -> **contradiction**

If Switch 4 is wrong, then

> (B,C/E,D,?,A), only choices left for ? are C and E -> **contradiction**

If Switch 5 is wrong, then

> (B,C/E,D,A/C/E,?), one scenario can be (B,C/E,D,A,C/E) -> **possible**

Answer

> Form A: Switch 4; Wrong Sign: Switch 5

Answer (score 9):

Form A is available at

> Switch 4.

Assume

> Switch 1 was incorrect. This means that form B must be somewhere else. But there is no other sign which references form B, so that would mean more than one sign was incorrect (contradiction!). If we assume Switch 3 was incorrect, we’d get the same result. So one of Switches 2, 4, or 5 are wrong. It can’t be 4, because then B or D would have to be there too and those have already been placed. Assuming that Switch 2 was wrong would put A at Switch 2, but then Switch 5 would also be wrong. Therefore Switch 5 must be wrong, so all of the others are right, and since Switch 4 is the only place with mention to A, it must be there.

Comment: you sniped me with only the answer, but i have the full explanation first. let the judge decide! good game!

Answer (score 3):

> Let us assume for contradiction sake Switch 5 was correct. If Switch 1 and 3 are correct only C and E are left for Switches 2 and 4 which would thus be correct, too. Similarly if Switches 2 and 4 are correct only B and D are left for Switch  1 and 3 and either both or none of them is correct. Thus, there is no way that Switch 5 is correct and exactly one of the remaining switches incorrect. This implies that Switch 5 must be the incorrect one. The only Switch remaining which could possibly contain Form A is Switch 4.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to the **Puzzling Stack Exchange (PSE)**! Great job on your first answer! I'm glad you have learnt to use the spoiler tag `>!` and have even answered the question correctly — and pretty nicely too with a thorough explanation! — so well done! Take the [*tour*](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) if you have not already, just to get a clearer understanding of what this site is all about, as well as the community thriving on it. Also, check out the [*Help Center*](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help) to know how you may contribute to this community. Apart from that, enjoy! :)

Answer (score 0):

> Terminal 4 is wrong as it must contain either Forms C or E, thusly Bob should go to Terminal 5 to retrieve Form A